# Heroku returns 403 forbidden after I make authentication in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, heroku

I'm trying to make authentication in my website.
But it didn't make out on Heroku.
My website shown 403 status after I made authentication in laravel.

The website index page said:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

All the commands I made are these:

```
composer require laravel/ui “^1.0” --dev

php artisan ui vue --auth

npm install

npm audit fix

npm run dev
```

These commands are like php artisan make:auth before Laravel 5.

I don't know how to fix now.
Whats the problem can be?

Comment: You must show us detailed logs, and explain what path/url you try access etc. Also your environment must be **development** for showing detailed error informations.

Comment: Actually I didn't add anything in this website yet. It's totally a brand new Laravel project.

Comment: What I did is following this video, except for authentication's part.    https://youtu.be/639Pe0PpVLQ

Comment: Can you access /register and /login pages?

Comment: No, I can't do that.

Comment: can you  access heroku terminal and write this command `php artisan route:list` in your project directory? you must see auth routes.

Comment: try this `composer dumpautoload` `php artisan cache:clear` `php artisan config:clear`. just to make your app cleared you cache on server

Comment: You mean these routes? https://i.imgur.com/cEqghBj.jpg

Comment: @Wiguna R   It didn't work